# Copy function in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy, display

Thank you so much for the support. I saw where the mistake was.

I wonder if its possible to make the input box as a drop down as well?

---

This code seems not to copy to "Sheet2"

I have this data set[image]

[image]

But when I checked my "Sheet2" it is blank. Did I miss something?

Thanks a lot for your advice

`Sub SearchForString()

```
Dim LSearchRow As Integer
Dim LCopyToRow As Integer
Dim LSearchValue As String

On Error GoTo Err_Execute

LSearchValue = InputBox("Please enter a value to search for.", "Enter value")

'Start search in row 4
LSearchRow = 4

'Start copying data to row 2 in Sheet2 (row counter variable)
LCopyToRow = 2

While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0

    'If value in column E = LSearchValue, copy entire row to Sheet2
    If Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue Then

        'Select row in Sheet1 to copy
        Rows(CStr(LSearchRow) & ":" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Select
        Selection.Copy

        'Paste row into Sheet2 in next row
        Sheets("Sheet2").Select
        Rows(CStr(LCopyToRow) & ":" & CStr(LCopyToRow)).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste

        'Move counter to next row
        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1

        'Go back to Sheet1 to continue searching
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    End If

    LSearchRow = LSearchRow + 1

Wend

'Position on cell A3
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("A3").Select

MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."

Exit Sub
```

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `Select`, you can simply stay what cell you're actually looking for as Vityata said.

All the selecting will slow you down.

Instead of:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("A5").Select
ActiveCell.Copy
```

You can simply do

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A5").Copy
```

You may also consider using `With` statements if you're going to be referencing a sheet a lot.

`With` statements let you leave off parts of the string.

So you can simply say:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Cells(1,1) = "Hi"    'Same as Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1)
    .Cells(1,2) = "Hello" 'Same as Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,2)
End With
```

Just a few pointers - let me know if you have any questions.

Here's your code simplified.

```
Sub SearchForString()
Dim c, LSearchValue, LSearchRow, LCopyToRow, LastRow
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
LSearchValue = InputBox("Please enter a value to search for.", "Enter value")
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.CountLarge, "D").End(xlUp).Row
LSearchRow = 4
LCopyToRow = 2
For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & LSearchRow & ":D" & LastRow)
    If c = LSearchValue Then
        c.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(LCopyToRow, "A")
        LCopyToRow = LCopyToRow + 1
    End If
Next c
Application.CutCopyMode = False
MsgBox "All matching data has been copied."
Exit Sub
ErrHandle: MsgBox "An Error Has Occured: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Sheet1 Input:

[image: Input]

Sheet2 Output:

[image: Sheet2 Output]

Comment: Thank you very much for your message. I obviously had the columns wrong. When I changed it; then it worked. But somehow I had to update the code. I am stuck a bit with the "Please enter a value" would that be possible to have a drop down there instead. Like a combo box?

Comment: Sure - remove the inputbox line and set `LSearchValue =` to the cell value you want to check (example: `LSearchValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`). Then, just use data validation or whatever else to create a dropdown list from a range.

Answer (score 1):

In general, from your screenshot, "Mailbox" is in column `D`, and you are checking column `E`. Write "Mailbox" in column `E` and it should work.

---

Nevertheless:

The problem is that you do not refer to the worksheet, thus VBA refers to the `ActiveSheet`. E.g., instead of:

```
Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue
```

you should write:

```
Worksheets(2).Range("E" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value = LSearchValue
```

Or instead of:

```
While Len(Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0
```

the code should be like this:

```
While Len(Worksheets(1).Range("A" & CStr(LSearchRow)).Value) > 0
```

Thus, try to rewrite the code, defining correctly the `Range`, `Column`, `Rows`, `Cell` with the corresponding `Worksheet(1)` and it should probably work. In general, using `Select` and `ActiveCell` is considered bad practice - [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba), but it is the first step, when you going from recording macros to VBA writing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your corrections and help. I would like to add a drop down box where it says please enter a value. Is that possible?